# Show ListItemSecondaryAction on hover not working - React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show the secondary actions on hover. I saw an example written in MUI v4 but it doesnt work when I convert to MUI v5. Please advice.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemSecondaryAction from "@mui/material/ListItemSecondaryAction";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

function generate(element: React.ReactElement) {
  return [0, 1, 2].map((value) =>
    React.cloneElement(element, {
      key: value
    })
  );
}

export default function InteractiveList() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 752 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <List>
            {generate(
              <ListItem
                sx={{
                  "&:hover >.MuiListItemSecondaryAction-root": {
                    visibility: "inherit"
                  }
                }}
              >
                <ListItemText primary="Single-line item" />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction sx={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
                  <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItem>
            )}
          </List>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-babycat-zp6jfc